# Can't connect to docker mysql container via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I created a docker container from mysql:5.7 image.

```
sudo docker run --name mysqltest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -v mysql:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql:5.7
```

And I Created a php container that included phpunit

```
sudo docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app phpunit/phpunit:8 phpunit --testdox file.php
```

in file.php I'm trying to connect mysql container, via mysql container ip as host:

```
sudo docker inspect mysqltest
```

but still I get "connection Refused", but I can connect to mysql container directly via :

```
sudo docker exec -it mysqltest mysql -ppassword
```

Please Help me, I'm really confused !

Comment: you should check on docker-compose to make teh 3306 port available. Also check how you can use an external folder, so that after a restart you keeo all your data

Comment: How are you configuring the database connection in your application?  Can you include the test image's `Dockerfile` or any other relevant source code?

Answer (score 0):

The connection is refused as you are not exposing MySQL ports, so it is not seen by the host and the other containers. The proper way of handling these cases is by using docker-compose and custom docker networks, however, the following changes can act as a quick-fix:

```
sudo docker run --name mysqltest -p 3306:3306 --network=host -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -v mysql:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql:5.7
```

Followed by:

```
sudo docker run --network=host --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app phpunit/phpunit:8 phpunit --testdox file.php
```

`-p 3306:3306` tells Docker to map default port of MySQL inside the container to port `3306` of the host. `--network=host` directs docker to use your local machine network stack. You can verify MySQL being accessible by trying to connect to it from your machine on port `3306` with any of its client applications. 
Note that you need to update your application configurations to use the MySQL database on `localhost`.

Comment: thanks for help, connection established but I got ( Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' ). There is a ambiguity for me, is docker use my local MySQL that installed on my machine?

Comment: if I use to set own docker IP as host ( e.g: 172.20.0.2 ), what have I to do ?

Comment: You need to either stop your local mysql or map the container's to an unoccupied port `-p 3307:3306` will map your local machine's 3307 port to the dockerized mysql. In this case you need to update the configs to use this new port when connecting to the mysql container.

Comment: Use `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -P 3307  -p` and enter the password you specified (in this case `password`.

Comment: I try to connect MYSQL container via PHP script and exactly with information as you said, but I've got "No Route to Host" on port 3307. I'm really confused and I really don't know what to do!

Comment: Are you using `127.0.0.1` in your php code? Is the command above working when you try to connect with mysql client?